# Water going into new water heater on cold side

Tags: plumbing, water, water-heater

We installed a new water heater. When you turn on just the cold water you can feel it going into the water heater on the cold side. Is this normal?

Comment: And then the hot water faucets will blow air quite dramatically. Less drama results if you open all, or at least one of, the hot water faucets, the hot water shut off from the heater, and then the cold water input to the heater, so air can be pushed out under less pressure. Regardless, don't turn on the heater until the air is out of it - if electric you can fry an element in seconds if it's in air, not water.

Comment: Is this after the air has been purged from your water heater and hot water lines?  Where are you turning on the cold water - at a fixture, shower, or supply going into the heater?  If all of the air is purged and you're feeling cold water still going into the heater, does hot water eventually come out of the fixture you've turned on (with only the cold open)?

Answer (score 2):

As installed, your water tank has air at whatever atmospheric pressure you live at (lets call it 15psi absolute for example). Your inlet water supply has some higher pressure, say 60psi (gauge, so 75psi absolute, could well be higher).

With all other valves closed you open the cold water tap. Water will flow in and start occupying volume in the tank, compressing the air trapped in the tank. This will continue until the air pressure matches the inlet water pressure. For the particular numbers above that means that the tank will be 80% full of water, and 20% full of air at 60psi (gauge). When you open a hot water tap you will get a flow of air under pressure for a while as that compressed air is let out and additional water flows in.

As noted in the comments, it is best to have the hot water outlet valve open to let the air out gracefully.